# Create Excel 2007 or 2010 custom task pane using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to build a Custom Task Pane for `Excel 2007 or 2010` without `Visual Studio`, that is, using only `VBA`?

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073929/display-html-page-in-office-2003-or-2007-task-pane-via-vba) but it's not working for me.

Comment: The previous answer suggests that you must use Visual Studio. I think that answers your question.  What have you tried so far? (Show your code).

Comment: I tried following a tutorial to do this with Visual Studio but can't even get started with it, therefore I'm trying to go back to VBA.

Comment: You can make a custom ribbon tab with XML - it's quite easy, but doesn't work on the Mac. Would that suit your purpose? Otherwise, you can have a tabbed user form. Maybe a combination of the two will do what you need.

Comment: @Floris my idea is to make a list of comments in a spreadsheet, therefore I need a vertical interface and thus the task pane, if I can't make it, I'll try the custom ribbon.

Comment: The following link may be a good place to start: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, as of now, the answer to your question is "No".

As far as I can tell, extending any Office application (Excel, PowerPoint, etc.) with a Custom Task Pane / Application Pane requires a COM add-in, that needs to be developed with Visual Studio.

At least for Office 2007, this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338197%28v=office.12%29.aspx) specifically states that:

> (..) custom task panes are deployed as Component Object Model (COM)
>   add-ins (..)

The same article states that VBA does not support creating such custom task panes.

> You can create custom task panes in any language that supports COM and
>   that enables you to create dynamic-linked library (DLL) files, for
>   example, Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0, Microsoft Visual Basic .NET,
>   Microsoft Visual C++, Microsoft Visual C++ .NET, and Microsoft Visual
>   C. **However, Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) does not
>   support creating custom task panes.** Custom task panes use other
>   technologies with which you are already familiar, for example,
>   Microsoft ActiveX controls.

This article shows how to create a custom task pane with C# or VB in VS2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846.aspx

All in all, this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx) states that you need Microsoft Office Developer Tools for developing office solutions, which is only bundled with

- Visual Studio Professional
- Visual Studio Premium
- Visual Studio Ultimate

If you only have VBA available it seems like your are stuck with the original User Forms for now.

Comment: Seems to be very easy (and free) to install Visual Studio Community + Office Development tools though: https://www.visualstudio.com/features/office-tools-vs

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking the same question.
I "think" the only way to make CTP is through VS.
And only way to make in VBA is with userFrom instead of custom task pane.