# Add a title bar below the ribbon in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

How do I add a bar below the ribbon in MS Project so that I can display a title or other information?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible in VBA, but possible in Visual Studio

Visit [Create Excel 2007 or 2010 custom task pane using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567045/create-excel-2007-or-2010-custom-task-pane-using-vba)